# I'm trying to create a wordcloud with this python code, but keeps getting error

Tags: python, word-cloud

the code below is written in python in Jupyter notebook.

## Function to Create WordCloud

```
def create_word(text):

    mask = np.array (Image.open("cloud.png"))
    stopwords = set (STOPWORDS)
    wc= WordCloud(background_color="white",
                 mask= mask,
                 max_words=3000,
                 stopwords=stopwords,
                 repeat=True)
    wc.generate(str(text))
    wc.to_file("wc.png")
    print("Word Cloud Saved Successfully")
    path="wc.png"
    display(Image.open(path))
```

## Creating wordcloud for tweet analysis

```
create_wordcloud(tw_list["text"].values)
```

**This is the error generated**

```
<ipython-input-83-57370aac7740> in create_wordcloud(text)
      3
      4 def create_wordcloud(text):
----> 5     mask = np.array(Image.open("cloud.png"))
      6     stopwords = set(STOPWORDS)
      7     wc = WordCloud(background_color="white",

 ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py in open(fp, mode, formats)

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'cloud.png'
```

Comment: place the image in same path as your python script file or use absolute path

Comment: thanks for the response. but can you please illustrate that in an example for me.

Answer (score 0):

download cloud.png and wc.png files from the following GitHub https://github.com/yalinyener/TwitterSentimentAnalysis

then upload to your source location